# gcc optimization of struct assignment

Tags: gcc, optimization

Here is my example code:

```
struct AAA {
    union{
        struct{
            int a;
            int b; 
        };
        long A;
    };

    union{
        struct{
            short c;
            char d;
            char e;
        };
        int B;
    };
} __attribute__((packed));

void fun1(struct AAA *aaa){
    aaa->a = 1;
    aaa->b = 2;
    aaa->c = 3;
    aaa->d = 4;
    aaa->e = 5;
}

void fun2(struct AAA *aaa){
    aaa->A = (2L<<32)+1;
    aaa->B = (5 << 24) + (4<<16) + 3;
}
```

When I compile it to asm code using gcc 5.4.0, I got:

```
fun1:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    $3, %eax
        movl    $1, (%rdi)
        movl    $2, 4(%rdi)
        movw    %ax, 8(%rdi)
        movb    $4, 10(%rdi)
        movb    $5, 11(%rdi)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   fun1, .-fun1
        .section        .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE0:
        .text
.LHOTE0:
        .section        .text.unlikely
.LCOLDB1:
        .text
.LHOTB1:
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  fun2
        .type   fun2, @function
fun2:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        movabsq $8589934593, %rax
        movl    $84148227, 8(%rdi)
        movq    %rax, (%rdi)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

And when I compile it with gcc 7.3.0, I got

```
fun1:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movabsq $8589934593, %rax
        movl    $84148227, 8(%rdi)
        movq    %rax, (%rdi)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   fun1, .-fun1
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  fun2
        .type   fun2, @function
fun2:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        movabsq $8589934593, %rax
        movl    $84148227, 8(%rdi)
        movq    %rax, (%rdi)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Both using -O3 option. The difference is obvious. Newer versions of gcc optimizes `fun1` just like `fun2`.

Is `fun2` really faster than `fun1` when generating by gcc 5.4.0?

I have some old projects and they are compiled using even older versions of gcc (4.x), and I found many similar code like my example. If I want to do optimization, is it a good idea to change `fun1` to `fun2`? I can't update gcc for now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these programs are running on modern CPU architectures, the difference would be in the measure of nanoseconds.

Unless your code consists mostly of these assignments, and you really need to squeeze out the tiny bit of performance, I would keep it the same as `fun1` for better readability and maintainability.